# Problema dllimport C# en web

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estimados,
me ha resultado muy difícil encontrar la solución a este problema:

resulta que estoy usando unas dll de terceros las cuales no se pueden integrar al proyecto en visual studio. Usando la función dllImport he logrado usarlas sin problemas en una aplicación de escritorio de pruebas que realice, ahora me propongo a traspasarla a web, pero esta no funciona, ni siquiera me da algún error con el que trabajar simplemente se queda en una carga infinita.
 He leído que podría ser por la ubicación de las dll en cuestión, en el proyecto de escritorio las puse en la carpeta bin del proyecto, lo mismo que en la web, pero en uno funciona y en el otro no.

El código que uso para esta es:

```
[DllImportAttribute("ejemplo.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenIPPort", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]

public static extern int OpenIPPort(System.IntPtr ip_address, int tcp_port);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La libreria que estas intentando usar fue creada con C o C++ con lo cual es una dll no manajeada.

Deberias copiarla a la carpeta `C:\Windows\System32`

Luego habilita los 32bit en el sitio web en el IIS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien valida que el Identity del Application Pool ejecuta con un usuario que tienes privilegios elevandos, podrias en principio usa un usuario que sea admin local

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]